# pcap_next causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c, libpcap

I'm writing a simple packet capture program which captures three packets using pcap functions. But it crashes with a segmentation fault. Below is the source code for the program.

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dump.h"

void pcap_fatal(const char *failed_in, const char *errbuf){
    printf("Fata Error in %s: %s\n", failed_in, errbuf);
    exit(1);
}

int main(){
    struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
    const u_char *packet;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char *device;
    pcap_t *pcap_handle;
    int i;

    /*look for a device to capture packets*/
    device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if(device == NULL)
        pcap_fatal("pcap_lookupdev", errbuf);
    printf("Sniffing on device %s\n", device);

    /*opens the packet capturing device*/
    pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 4096, 1, 0, errbuf);
    if(pcap_handle < 0){
        perror("ERROR: while opening pcap device");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n===packet %d===\n", i+1);
        packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, header);
        printf("Got a %d bute packet\n", header->len);
        dump(packet, header->len);
    }
    
    pcap_close(pcap_handle);
}
```

Can you figure out what is going on ??

Comment: `struct pcap_pkthdr *header` is never initialised! Use `struct pcap_pkthdr header;` to just create a header instead of a pointer and get its pointer with `&header`

Comment: Here you have a working example which uses `pcap_next()`: https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/pcap_next/cpp-pcap_next-function-examples.html

Comment: @SamBob        I did that but that didn't work. The program still crashes with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding condition `if(pcap_handle < 0)`: the API documentation here,
https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html, indicates that function "`pcap_open_live()` returns a `pcap_t *` on success and `NULL` on failure.  The error check should probably be `if(pcap_handle == NULL)` in this case.

In the current program, if `pcap_open_live()` were to return `NULL` indicating a failure, then I would expect line `packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, header);` to either crash due to pcap_handle being set to NULL, or to set `header` to `NULL` or else leave it in its uninitialized state by recognizing `pcap_handle` being set to `NULL` as an error.

On the following line, `header` is dereferenced, and if uninitialized or `NULL` would likely result in a segmentation fault.

So to summarize see the comments added below:

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dump.h"

void pcap_fatal(const char *failed_in, const char *errbuf){
    printf("Fata Error in %s: %s\n", failed_in, errbuf);
    exit(1);
}

int main(){
    struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
    const u_char *packet;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char *device;
    pcap_t *pcap_handle;
    int i;

    /*look for a device to capture packets*/
    device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if(device == NULL)
        pcap_fatal("pcap_lookupdev", errbuf);
    printf("Sniffing on device %s\n", device);

    /*opens the packet capturing device*/
    pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 4096, 1, 0, errbuf); // << Fails and returns NULL.
    if(pcap_handle < 0){                                      // << Passes since value is NULL (typically zero).
        perror("ERROR: while opening pcap device");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n===packet %d===\n", i+1);
        packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, header);              // << Crashes due to pcap_handle being NULL, sets header to NULL or leaves uninitialized.
        printf("Got a %d bute packet\n", header->len);        // << Dereferences pointer to nothing causing segmentation fault.
        dump(packet, header->len);
    }
    
    pcap_close(pcap_handle);
}
```

I would recommend the following replacement code with a few extra checks for added protection:

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dump.h"

void pcap_fatal(const char *failed_in, const char *errbuf){
    printf("Fata Error in %s: %s\n", failed_in, errbuf);
    exit(1);
}

int main(){
    struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
    const u_char *packet;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char *device;
    pcap_t *pcap_handle;
    int i;

    /*look for a device to capture packets*/
    device = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if(device == NULL)
        pcap_fatal("pcap_lookupdev", errbuf);
    printf("Sniffing on device %s\n", device);

    /*opens the packet capturing device*/
    pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 4096, 1, 0, errbuf);
    if(pcap_handle == NULL){
        perror("ERROR: while opening pcap device");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n===packet %d===\n", i+1);
        packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, header);
        if((packet != NULL) && (header != NULL)){
            printf("Got a %d bute packet\n", header->len);
            dump(packet, header->len);
        }
    }
    
    pcap_close(pcap_handle);
}
```

Comment: "In the current program, if `pcap_open_live()` were to return `NULL` indicating a failure, then I would expect line `packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, header);` to set `header` to NULL or else leave it in its uninitialized state."   I would expect `pcap_next()` to attempt to use `pcap_handle` as a pointer and crash trying to use members of that structure.

Comment: "The error check should probably be `if(pcap_handle == NULL)` in this case."  Yes, exactly.  `if(pcap_handle < 0)` will almost certainly *not* detect an error - it'll think `pcap_open_live()` succeeded.  Functions that return pointers usually return `NULL` on errors; functions that return an *integer* value often return negative values as error indications.  `pcap_open_live()` returns a pointer.

Comment: @user16139739 I am assuming that `pcap_next()` checks `pcap_handle` and `header` for NULL as part of its own error checking, but the documentation doesn't explicitly state this.  However, if `pcap_next()` does not include a null check, then yes it would fail.  Either way, if it were ever to make it to line `printf("Got a %d bute packet\n", header->len);`, then it will definitely fail due to dereferencing a Null pointer.

Comment: "I am assuming that `pcap_next()` checks pcap_handle and header for NULL as part of its own error checking, but the documentation doesn't explicitly state this."  The documentation doesn't state it, because it's not the case.  libpcap assumes that the writer of the code does the right error checking when opening a device or a capture file.  If the documentation doesn't say something, don't assume it's the case.

Comment: @user16139739 As a practice, I would typically perform `NULL` checks inside of any library functions and generate an error code rather than allowing the pointer to be dereferenced, but I can agree that this is not always the case.  I have modified the response to cover both scenarios.  All in all, the main point is that the program will crash if `pcap_handle ` is set to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan S. said, your test for `pcap_open_live()` is wrong.

You should do

```
/*opens the packet capturing device*/
pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 4096, 1, 0, errbuf);
if(pcap_handle == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: while opening pcap device %s: %s\n", device, errbuf);
    exit(1);
}
```

because:

1. `pcap_open_live()` returns a null pointer on an error - it doesn't return a negative number, because it doesn't return a number;
2. the error indication is not an errno value, so `perror()` won't report the error correctly - `errbuf` contains a string describing the error, so you want to print it so you know *why* it failed;
3. you should also report the device name, as that may also be useful in determining why `pcap_open_live()` failed.

Note also that, on most UN*X platforms (Linux, *BSD, macOS, etc.) you may need to run your program with elevated privileges, such as root privileges, in order to open a network interface for capturing, so if your program reports a permission error after you've fixed it to use the code above, try running it as root.